# Is it safe to signup multiple applications with facebook?

Tags: passwords, password-management, password-cracking

Putting all eggs in one basket.. Is it safe to sign-up on different applications with facebook or such similar platforms, linkedin, twitter etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it safe to signup on multiple applications with single email address? The same thing applies here too. One thing is when you sign up on other applications through social networks, your circle may get notifications of your activity. If you have privacy issues, you can set your social media settings to private. Keep your passwords and security questions strong.

Comment: I think it might be worth noting though that when you log in with social media you have a single password for all the accounts associated with said account, so if the social media account is compromised, so are all the associated accounts.

Comment: If the email ID is compromised, all your associated accounts on which you have signed up with this email will be compromised. The 2nd fact is that if you sign up on multiple applications with the same password (that most laymen do) can also compromise you greatly. So I think using social authentication is more secure in this sense as applications will get an only auth token with permissions instead of the password.

Comment: It could be argued that in the case of e-mail, if strong passwords are used, the attacker would need to take time to reset the passwords of each individual account, while if they gain access to a social media account it means they have instant access to everything that's connected. Maybe if all email were deleted it would add a bit of security through obscurity while all associated apps to a social media account are usually listed. That being said, I'm not sure there's that much of a difference either way.